# loading multiple tiff images as matrices from a dir

Tags: matlab, matrix, import, tiff

my problem is this one:
I have a directory full of .tif images and I want to import them in MATLAB each one as a matrix.

If I do right click on the file in the dir and say "Import Data" it works: I have a matrix of elements that are my pixels that I can treat with imagesc and so on.

**I want to make it automatic with a script.**

what I have written is this one but it opens the Import Wizard, ask me to click enter for importing the first one and then stops.

```
    contents = dir('*pulse1us100ms26_00*'); % this is part of the name of the images I want to load
    for i = 1:numel(contents)
      filename = contents(i).name;
      uiimport(filename);
    end
```

***??? Error using ==> uiimport at 65
Cannot open the Import Wizard on a file while the Import Wizard is open.***

May you please help me?

Comment: The error that id displays is this one


**Error using ==> uiimport at 65
Cannot open the Import Wizard on a file while the Import Wizard is open. **


Basically I think it cannot go trough step two of the for loop because he is waiting for me to click enter and import manually the image. I don't know how to fix this. Sorry if I didn't post the error before.

Comment: I think [imread](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) is probably what you are looking for as mentioned by Ed Smith but I think it would be better if you posted a sample image. It is kind of difficult to know why you get errors without it.

Answer (score 0):

I think imread may be what you need,

```
% this is part of the name of the images I want to load
contents = dir('pulse1us100ms26_00*'); 
for i = 1:numel(contents)
    filename = contents(i).name;
    im = imread(filename,'tiff');
    imagesc(im(:,:,1:3))
    pause(3)
end
```

The result will be a matrix of uint8 from 0 to 255 (depending on the picture format). You can then work with them as needed.

Comment: ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> loadingtiff at 7
    im(i) = imread(filename);

Comment: Sorry, does it work now (the im(i) was a typo). Also added format 'tiff' to imread. You may need to use only the first three channels, e.g. imagesc(im(:,3)) to display depending on the tiff format

Comment: It works but it just shows me the images and my objective is to load the images as matrices inside my workspace. The point is that I don't need the images as they are, I have to clear them working with the values that are storaged inside every pixel, that basically is what I can do if I just do right click and "Import Data", but I have to make it automatically and don't do it everytime by hand.

I thought that the right command was `uiimport` as it lets start the Import Wizard but it gave me the first error I posted.

Comment: I think I have found what I was looking for thanks to your advice:
`contents = dir('*pulse1us100ms26_00*');
a=zeros(2048,2048);
for i = 1:numel(contents)
    filename = contents(i).name;
    im = imread(filename,'tiff');
    a=[a,im];
end
s=size(a);
p=s(2)/2048;
b=reshape(a,2048,2048,p); `

Maybe it is not that elegant and I still have to eliminate the first matrix that is all zero but I think it works. 
Thank you very much for helping me.